# Decoupling redshift

Tags: cosmology, space-expansion

How is the Decoupling Redshift calculated or derived from the 6 base cosmological parameters?

The decoupling redshift is usually showed to be 1089.9.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to see the exact derivation is from the Dodelson book. In essence one calculates the equilibrium temperature and then the expansion Hubble parameter for a matter dominated universe (which is when it happened) will give you the scale parameter a and the redshift z. Dodelson does not have the latest parameters, but you can get that from the Planck data, and anyway Dodelson is close. The main piece of work in the calculation is using the Boltzmann and then Saha equations to get the equilibrium temperature when (approximately) the mean free path equals the Hubble rate. Dodelson is the best explanation I've seen.

A simple description of the concept is at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decoupling_(cosmology), but it's pretty basic. A little more in http://star-www.st-and.ac.uk/~spd3/Teaching/AS2001/ce04.pdf, where they calculate 5700K and say that a more exact calculation will give you the near 3000K correct value. The following has a more complete treatment, though it is from 2006 and his parameters are not the latest, but he comes close, see it at http://www.helsinki.fi/~hkurkisu/cosmology/Cosmo6.pdf

As you can see the main calculations have to do with working with the Saha equation and getting the equilibrium temperature.